# Aura component working in preview but gives a 404 when published

Tags: community, aura

I need to add some custom Javascript on a Community experience builder site. For this I have created an Aura component, including a reference to a custom script I have created as a static resource. Running the site in preview finds this component and the Javascript runs fine, but publishing to the live site gives a 404 error trying to find this.
Apologies, I am a newbie at this so likely a really basic point I'm missing, but if someone could give me a pointer it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

**MyComponent.cmp**

<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.myJS}" />
</aura:component>

**myJS.js**

console.log("Test");

Comment: Have you checked the cache control setting for your static resource? This might need to be changed to 'Public'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response Callum. It was indeed down to the cache control being private by default so I received a 404 when viewing the site as an unauthenticated user.

I got to this from the Community Experience Builder site, but clicking in the top left menu, selecting Administration, then Pages in the left menu, under Advanced Customizations clicking go to Force.com.
On this website searching for Static Resources in the Quick Find menu, and then editing my file in the list changing the cache control from Private to Public.

Many thanks again for your help.